# How to create an index in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

Every book has an "Index" at the end and using which we find specific text in the book.

I have created a document in LibreOffice Writer and now I want to create the "Index" like the same in a book. I can manually do that by selecting words and putting page numbers against them. But after doing so, if I add a couple of pages in the mid I have to redo the indexing again, that is terrible.

I imagine a feature, that lists all the words in my document and let me choose the words which should go in the index. Then the index is automatically created. If the page numbers change after creating the index, then the index is automatically updated. If I delete some words in the document that are already in the index, then the index is automatically updated.

Is my dream feature (or similar) available in LibreOffice Writer? If so, please explain how to do it.

Comment: What you asked is worthwhile and I would like the same feature, that and/or be able to feed the indexer a predefined list of entries, but the wording of your question is much too generic. So generic in fact that you got a generic answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice / OpenOffice writer can **create and maintain indices automatically**. You just have to define the index entries. To create a index entry, select the word to put in the index, and select Menu "`Insert`" -> "`Indices and Tables`" -> "`Entry...`":

[image]

There, optionally, you can define a different key for the current word. There's also a very nice feature "`Apply to all similar texts`": this will create index entries **for every other occurrence of that word**, so you don't have to define every occurrence of the word as index entry.